# $(window).hashchange() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Hi**,

I'm trying to use the browser back button, i understood how to catch the event with hashchange plugin =>

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    alert( location.hash );
});$(window).hashchange();
```

When i try to load the new page, nothing happens..
Is there a way to "reload" the page with the new url ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 19):

Try this instead:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    // Your code goes here
}).trigger('hashchange'); // bind event to the same selector as event-listener
```

[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) basicly activates events manually.

**EDIT:**
This should be enough for you to work.

Try [this piece of code](http://jsfiddle.net/HNMfU/2/) and see if you got any luck.

Included javascript.js is compressed with jquery and hashchange.

Comment: Are you using `$(function() { /* Code here */ })` around it? Do you include the hashchange.js extension correctly? Does your webbrowser get any javascript error?

Comment: yes i'm using it around the code. The file is well included and no error is detected by firebug

Comment: I suppose you can try `$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {});` instead of just `hashchange()`. That's what I'm using and it works.

Comment: $(function()
{
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() 
    {
 console.log( location.hash+"  -  "+window.location);
 
    });
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});

This is what i'm doing and still doesn't work..

Comment: Check my link and see if you have more luck.

Answer (score 3):

Put `$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {});` outside of the document.ready