# My site keeps crashing on my Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

For some reason my site won't operate in Google Chrome. It works flawlessly in Firefox without special errors, but is a no-no in Chrome. What gives?

<del>http://www.lemaineofficial.com/</del>

[image: Chrome Error]
(It says an error has occured, and that I can try to reload. However it gives same error always)

The moment my javascript wants to get executed (it loads the site briefly), Chrome just aborts the page. I've never seen an error like this and have no idea how to troubleshoot except removing functions till it works, which I will try to do.

I just need to know what can cause this behavior on Chrome with javascript, or know how to easily troubleshoot it.

**Note:** This site works as intended with Firefox without crashes.

### EDIT #1:

This error doesn't necessarily mean it's due to javascript after further checking. I can asume I'm not alone in having this error, but is there someone with Chrome who can view the site? Thanks for your theories. I'll update if I get any wiser on this.

### EDIT #2:

Something here seems to cause the problem, but every value defined is required

```
body.visitor_mode div#content {
    /* Outruled cause */
    -webkit-column-gap: 5vw;
    -moz-column-gap: 5vw;
    column-gap: 5vw;
    -webkit-column-width: 45vw;
    -moz-column-width: 45vw;
    column-width: 45vw;
}
```

Is there anything in here that causes Chrome crashes ?

### Edit #3:

I've solved this issue for me now. It was caused by using `column-gap` and `column-width` and the unit `vw`, which Chrome didn't seem to like. I remade this behavior in javascript instead as given in Simons answer.

At the moment the only thing I'm missing is the "correct `.width()` from my `column-width`. Firefox gives me the actual width, while Chrome simply gives me the `column-width` value. Thanks to Simons edit, I managed to get half a good solution. However, I used css `transition`, which makes `offset().left` unreliable. Is there any other way to get that value?

Comment: one possible way to debug is to remove some portion of the code till the page is working... then the last removed portion can be reviewed

Comment: That's the last resort I'm intending to do, but since I've never in my years come across this behavior, I'd like to know what causes it to work in Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: if it helps it crash on chrome for me, so it must be so bad js code. follow arun's suggest and clean up your http://www.lemaineofficial.com/formize/js_files/cmp_.js file

Comment: even with javascript disabled it crashes!

Comment: Chrome has been doing this for many sites for me recently. Haven't found a pattern in it yet.

Comment: We need to get the console log. When you see the error, press F12, go to Console tab and copy everything you see there and share it here.

Comment: Can't track nor receive any special info before nor after the site loads and error occurs with F12 Console.

Comment: Chrome console: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://www.lemaineofficial.com/formize/js_files/cmp_.js". Is your file goes thru php with wrong header ?

Comment: You're correct. I fixed that earlier, and it must be a cache issue if you still get it. However, it seems to be irrelevant to this error since it still persists.

Comment: Another Chrome console error msg : Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.lemaineofficial.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. So I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876656/youtube-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-www-youtube-com-from-accessing-a-f

Comment: I've tried it on Safari/Mac now and it crashed too !

Comment: I suggest you to first disable social media plugin i suspect there may be a problem because from here if i click on close button before page fully loaded then it is working

Comment: Have you tried to use position() instead of offset()? With position() it is woring correctly, even with transitions.

Comment: True story! Thanks once again. I just mised them up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be part of the css in the iframe `/page/story`.
When you change the units in `-webkit-column-gap` from `vw` to `px` (or remove it completely) it completely messes up the layout of the iframe but it doesn't crash the browser tab anymore.

I think this is a bug in the Chrome rendering engine which does break with the new `vw` unit in the `column-gap` css property.

If you want a simple two column layout i suggest use two divs with

```
<div style="width: 50%; float: left;"></div>
```

**EDIT**

One possible way is to change the css value with javascript using pixel values.

```
function onResize() {
    var width = 0.45 * $(window).width();
    var gap = 0.05 * $(window).width();
    $("#content")
        .css("-webkit-column-width", width + "px")
        .css("-webkit-column-gap", gap + "px");
}

$(function() {
    if (/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $(window).resize(onResize);
        onResize();
    }
});
```

**2nd Edit**

To get the width of the div containing the columns, you can insert

```
<span id="endmarker"></span>
```

and then get the left position with `$("#endmarker").position().left + columnWidth`, which is the total width of all columns. There is one special case when the content matches exactly (with no pixel space above or below the text) into two columns, the span seems to be moved to the first column for whatever reason.

**3rd Edit**

I found out a solution for the problem in the 2nd edit, if you add a space into the marker span (`<span id="endmarker">&nbsp;</span>`) the problem seems to be gone.

Comment: This would break the design since it's supposed to grow to the right. If you open main page in firefox and shrink it, you'll see what I mean. I'll try to search more on this and see if I can find a more ideal solution.

Comment: It's true that I can run this in javascript, and I may aswell do since I already use the resize event. Will get back to you on this one.

Comment: I've added it now; only one last problem. The `.width()` in chrome is of _one_ column, not all of them. How do I get total width like Firefox does?

Comment: How do you mean that? $(window).width() returns the total width of the window (the iframe in your case).

Comment: In Firefox, the `.width()` of `div.text` get increased if it splits to 3 or more columns, but in Chrome the `.width()` is only a sole column in width. I need to find out how to get entire width or get column amount of the `div`.

Comment: Look at the second edit, I didn't manage to get rid of this "element moves to the first column problem"...

Comment: Apart from that, the `.offset()` value switches when you're browsing... Chrome must have some reliable way to get the actual width, right ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it might be to do with your hashchange event. There's a post on StackOverflow where somebody else had trouble using it, might be worth a read: [$(window).hashchange() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597007/window-hashchange-doesnt-work)

I suggest commenting out

```
$(function() {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

and see if the page loads correctly, then work from there.

With regards to browser compatibility, I find this site useful: http://caniuse.com/#search=hash

Comment: The irony of you refering me to my own answer :D

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Story.html file which is loaded by iframe, you have some style definitions in body, move it to head section :) (that's not the problem, it just looks bad)

Also in that same style definition you have

**body.visitor_mode div#content**

Change it to

**body.visitor_mode div.content**

(which you are using in code btw :P)

And that solved the issue on my Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.66 @ 64bit Linux from Google Repo :P) - page has loaded succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Ok So here's my findings so far

All testing on a Mac

Chrome: Shows error like yours
FireFox: Works, but very laggy (i7 processor, 8gig ram and SSD), this shouldn't happen
Safari: Crashes.

When I checked safari's crashlog, I got the stack trace of the part that causes it:

```
0   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf08384 WebCore::RenderBlock::calcColumnWidth() + 260
1   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c89c9e7 WebCore::RenderBlock::recomputeLogicalWidth() + 119
2   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf072eb WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, int) + 139
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf06f84 WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 52
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf166d9 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutPositionedObjects(bool) + 441
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf07a98 WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, int) + 2104
6   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf06f84 WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 52
7   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf06ed7 WebCore::RenderView::layout() + 759
8   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf063b6 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 1702
9   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8bf05c65 WebCore::Document::updateLayoutIgnorePendingStylesheets() + 133
10  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c0c2d72 WebCore::Element::offsetHeight() + 18
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8c0c2d4d WebCore::jsElementOffsetHeight(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::Identifier const&) + 13
```

So this is a WebKit related crash, that's related to rendering the views, I'd suggest you check out your code and start removing parts till it works.

my first suggestion is to remove the huge amount of text that says:

> Brödtext som borde vara här! Brödtext som borde vara här!

and see if that helps, also you must reduce the background images' sizes, they're huge and if they won't kill most browsers due to memory issues, they'll eat up lots of your bandwidth.

Comment: @Johannes that was sometime ago, hardly recall what I did, but I either looked into the inspector `(Cmd + Option  + I)` menu and selected the debugger tab and set an uncaught exceptions breakpoint, OR dumped the contents of `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`, this is done on a Mac

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mostafa. I was curious as I'd never seen these kinds of logs and I've been trying to debug a rendering engine issue, which is rather difficult to do with the regular developer tools.

Comment: @Johannes glad to help, let me know if this doesn't work, i can try to remember a bit better what I did exactly !

Answer (score 0):

I know it is weird but sometimes cookies can cause this problem, it worked for me once. Delete all your cookies and try again.

Comment: This errors happens to more than my alone, so it's most likely not a cookie issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are VERY big (2048x1152) and you have 4pcs.

First try with smaller images and lets see if the Chrome can handle.

Also you should quantate your images.
Detect the resolution and send smaller images if don't have to display large ones.
( my FireFox also crashed(24.0) )

Comment: These images have worked flawlessly earlier on before Chrome starting rejecting the site.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd try commenting out your five javascript references on the server.  That's not too much work.  See if you get the sick folder icon.

If no sick folder appears, add one back in.  Pull it up in Chrome again.  Continue this process until you find the break point.

Then, report back your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if this helps but I was able to see an error in the chrome developer tools window.
[image]

In order to see this:
1. Open a new tab
2. Press F12 to open dev tools
3. Navigate to the website
4. Click the X on the black popup that says the target has crashed
5. Click the Console tab.